# How to make array in existing array's index, C#

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I make array in existing array's index without using pointer for e.g

```
float[] currentNode = new float[12]
float[] neighbour = new float[12]

neighbour[8] = new float[12]
neighbour[8] = currentNode;

and can access with neighbour[8][1]
```

other option is something using pointers.

```
float *pointer;
int []array = new int[12];
pointer = &array[0];

neighbour[8] = pointer
```

so does first solution possible w/o changing my both arrays ? any other solutions ?? .

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [Multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
int[,] myArray;
myArray = new int[,] {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}};   // OK
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that.

You have an array of float values, not an array of arrays.

Which means you cannot assign one element in the array (which holds a float value) a value which is an array.

You'd have to redefine your variables as:

```
float[][] neighbour = new float[12][];
```

This will declare an array of arrays, which means each element of the neighbour array can hold arrays of different lengths, or no array (`null`-reference).

If you want to declare a matrix, you can do it like this:

```
float[,] neighbour = new float[12, 8];
```

Comment: can I use it using pointers then, bcz my whole code is using both of these arrays and I dont wana change it nw..cant I just point that specific [8] index to a pointer array ?? and access it by array[8].pickSomeValue

Comment: No, you can't. The array holds float values, not pointers. You'll have to change your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You also could use generics:

```
List<List<float>> numbers = new List<List<float>>();
numbers.Add(new List<float>());
numbers.Add(new List<float>());
numbers[0].Add(2.3);
numbers[0].Add(5);
numbers[0].Add(8.74);
numbers[1].Add(6.8);
numbers[1].Add(9.87);
float aNumber = numbers[1][0]; //6.8
float anotherNumber = numbers[0][2]; //8.74
```